# Is it possible to match a url with xpath in a nightwatch assertion?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, nightwatchjs

In the nightwatch documentation I can see that there are both the [urlContains](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assert-urlContains)
and [urlEquals](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assert-urlEquals) assertions that can be specified in a nightwatch.js but these do not allow xpath selectors. I have applied the global parameter to use Xpath everywhere (I will explain below) but I am looking for a way to assert (in a fuzzy way) that the URL of the current page matches a pattern.

The reason is that I test on numerous instances of the same application which are distinguished by their subdomain(s). I am attempting to make my test automation run on any of these environments (without having to change or duplicate the tests).

Comment: Can you write your own function that has a regular expression pattern that does the matching?

Comment: Yes but want to be 100% there isn't a more maintainable way beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you can do this is by using:

```
browser
  .url(function(result) {
    //match result.value to expression here
  })
```

This is the best way I've been able to get the URL and doing any kind of matching with it.

Comment: @Rebecca-d were you able to find a solution?